# server side button click only when client side returns confirm

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have a button which has both client side and server side click event..I want the server side event to executed only when client side confirm method returns true..I was thinking if we define both the events and execute below code it should not fire server event when I hit cancel in confirm dialogue..am I doing something wrong here.

```
<asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" onclick="btn1_Click" OnClientClick="Hello()" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function Hello() {

        return confirm("approved");

    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly call confirm from the mark up like below

```
OnClientClick="return confirm('approved?');"
```

Comment: This works..but why the same code from a function does not work

Comment: @user505210 You need to say OnClientClick="return Hello()" to have it take the return value from the function.